# Android - Create an array of drawables from db

Tags: android, arrays, drawable

I have a table in the database which contains names of images: pic1, pic2, pic3 etc...
When this table is retrieved from the db I need to create an array of drawbles from the names of the pics eg:

```
private Integer[] pics = {
  R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,R.drawable.pic3}
```

The actuall images are in the drawable folder of the application.

How Can I achieve that?

10X!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Resources.getIdentifier()`:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
int id = res.getIdentifier("pic1", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
assert id == R.drawable.pic1;
```